# Connect to an access database in a remote directory using dao (VB6)

Tags: ms-access, vb6, jet

I need to replace this structure:

```
dim base as dao.database
set base = opendatabase ("c:\path\name.mdb")
```

with another in which the .mdb is located in a server directory. I tried:

```
dim base as dao.database
set base = opendatabase ("\\server\folder\name.mdb")
```

but it did not work. I'm using VB6. Any ideas?

Comment: Did not work how? e.g. did you see an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
set base = opendatabase ("\\server\folder\name.mdb")
```

Comment: Hi Sorry, I did use the \\, but forget to put it on the post